# Correct usage of verb and subject

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, clauses

I have a sentence that I am reasonably happy with, and it reads:

> I pray that your honest efforts pave the way for your success.

Why shouldn't it be:

> I pray that your honest efforts *paves* the way for your success.

It seems to be alright if I use:

> I pray that your honest *effort paves* the way for your success.

What part of grammar do I need to learn in order to remove such confusion when forming sentences?

Comment: You need to learn [subject-verb agreement](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp).

Comment: @Mick thank you so much. It was such a basic question I believe but this is the best site from which a beginner like me can learn and grow. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No. Leave it up. It may be useful if someone tidies it up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject of the two sentences you quote is either effort or efforts.  The first is singular, the second is plural.

When using effort (singular) use the proper conjugation of the verb 'to pave': 3rd person singular = 'paves'.

When using efforts (plural noun) use the proper conjugation: 3rd person plural = 'pave'.

Simplify the sentence to see it more clearly:

> My efforts pave the way
>
> Your efforts pave the way.
>
> His efforts pave the way.
>
> Our efforts pave the way

vs

> My effort paves the way

etc.

Do not be confused by the possessive pronoun.  My effort, your effort, his effort, our effort: those all take the 3rd person singular form of the verb.  I *pave* the way, but my effort *paves* the way.

Comment: This cleared everything! :)